# Visual Studio 2015 locks IIS when debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2015

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application in Visual Studio 2015. For debugging I run it on the IIS server (v7) installed on my development machine. 
Recently, when I change something in the source code and go to debug it Visual Studio says 'Trying to Contact the Web Server' then times out. When this happens the start menu (I am running Windows 7) becomes unresponsive (it opens but you cannot select an item or type anything in). I ultimately have to restart my machine, which is very time consuming.
I have tried running iisreset from the command prompt, but it doesn't fix the issue. It takes a long time to restart IIS.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to what may be causing this?

Comment: Have you test right clik on the project > Properties > Web > Enable Edit And Continue ?

Comment: No - it is disabled